# Inherit another object's methods

Tags: python

```
f = open('bobby_g.txt', 'w')
f.write('Hey bobby!')
f.close()

class BobFile:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self = open(x, 'r')


a = BobFile('bobby_g.txt')
print a.read()
a.close()
```

I don't want to subclass the 'file' object, I want to create a BobFile object that then becomes another object(a file object) (and inherits all of its methods).
So I can then use the BobFile object as if it were a file object..

Is this possible? I tried assigning the new file object to SELF of BobFile, but that didn't work...

Comment: You need to explain why `def BobFile(x): return open(x, 'r')` is not what you want.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the Factory-Pattern: have a Object, that produces other (maybe different types of) objects.

Comment: Why can't BobFile be a subclass of file?

Answer (score 2):

attribute delegation?

```
class BobFile:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__file = open(x,'r')
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.__file, name)

a = BobFile('/dev/random')
print a.read(20)
a.close()
```

Comment: It would be nice to know why inheritance is no option for the OP in the first place. Since BobFile really seems to be a file, this <emph>seems</emph> more like an instance of is-a rather than has-a.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? You can't create an object that becomes another object. Can you create a car that becomes an elephant? It's not reasonable. If you end up with something like this in your design, you should think of a new design.

So back up a little and think about what you're trying to do. If you just wish to do what your question says. Then simply create a class variable that you set to the file object in **init**. Then, create read() and close() methods in your BobbyFile class that call the respective methods of your file variable in the class.

Answer (score 1):

It is bit confusing after reading your question title and your description. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
class myfile(file):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        file.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

o = myfile('foo','w')
o.write('something')
o.close()
```